# geom_hist after using purrr::pmap to sample

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, purrr

I would like to use the results generated from `purrr::pmap` to plot histograms with reference lines for some quartiles.

I have the following data

```
   mean    sd     n
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
  5.00  3.00   100
  4.00  1.00   100
  4.00  2.00   100
```

Here is the data is a easily copy and pasted format

```
df <- tribble(
  ~mean,  ~sd,   ~n,
  5.00,  3.00,   100,
  4.00,  1.00,   100,
  4.00,  2.00,   100)
```

The code I have so far is

```
df %>% pmap(rnorm)
```

The problem is that I now have nested lists as opposed to a tidy dataframe. How can I tidy what I have to plot 3 histograms with reference lines for their median, 1st, and 3rd quartiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tidy the data with `unnest()`, but for this the `pmap`-call needs to be assigned to a column in your df (e.g. inside a `mutate` - call).

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(rnorm_data = pmap(list(n, mean, sd), rnorm)) %>% 
  group_by(mean_sd = interaction(mean, sd, sep = "_")) %>% 
  unnest() 

df
# A tibble: 300 x 5
# Groups:   mean_sd [3]
#     mean    sd     n mean_sd rnorm_data
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <fctr>      <dbl>
#  1     5     3   100     5_3   4.737157
#  2     5     3   100     5_3   5.221150
#  3     5     3   100     5_3   3.855733
#  4     5     3   100     5_3   8.965053
#  5     5     3   100     5_3   2.608563
#  6     5     3   100     5_3  11.940414
#  7     5     3   100     5_3   8.213685
#  8     5     3   100     5_3   6.332804
#  9     5     3   100     5_3   6.233713
# 10     5     3   100     5_3   4.758685
# # ... with 290 more rows
```

I added the `group_by` to refer to later in the `ggplot`-call and for summarizing the data in the following:

```
df_summarized <- df %>% 
  summarize(median = median(rnorm_data), 
            quart1st = quantile(rnorm_data, 0.25), 
            quart3rd = quantile(rnorm_data, 0.75)) %>% 
  gather(stat, value, median:quart3rd)
```

By using `gather` I can have different `linetypes` for different summary statistics.

```
ggplot(df, aes(rnorm_data, fill = mean_sd, color = mean_sd)) + 
  geom_histogram() + 
  geom_vline(data = df_summarized, 
             aes(xintercept = value, linetype = stat, color = mean_sd))
```

[image]

Comment: `mutate(rnorm_data = pmap(list(n, mean, sd), rnorm))` was the key for me.   `gather(stat, value, median:quart3rd) ` was also a big piece. Really great answer! Thanks!